# How to use Facebook accessToken from an iOS app to use in Rails / Facebooker

Tags: iphone, oauth, facebooker

I'm using iOS SDK to do Facebook Connect in an iPhone application, I can successfully login in and get the accessToken from the Facebook instance but I'm not able to use it from a rails/facebooker.

I do the call on the iPhone app:

```
NSString * url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://localhost:3000/fb_login?access_token=%@",[self.facebook accessToken],nil];
```

I'm passing the accessToken to an action on the rails app like this:

```
#auth_token comes from the iOS SDK.
facebook = Facebooker::Session.create('app_key','secret_key')
facebook.secure!(:auth_token => auth_token)
```

but I get Facebooker::Session::MissingOrInvalidParameter: "Invalid parameter"

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you fix your issue? I'm thinking about building something similar so I wanted to check if it's possible!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's because facebooker uses the old Facebook Connect authentication method. You may need to use the official facebook gem.

```
$ gem install facebook
```

But, I am not familiar with facebooker specifically, so I could be wrong!